# Kendo UI Web ListView and external templates and how to render HTML

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

When using Kendo UI Web ListView and external templates, i would like to know how do you print out the literal HTML to the browser.

This is what I have tried.

```
<p class="responsibilities">${ #= ResponsibilitiesHtml # } </p>
<p class="responsibilities">#= ${ ResponsibilitiesHtml } #</p>
//This Encodes the HTML    
<p class="responsibilities"> ${ ResponsibilitiesHtml } </p>
```

This just fails as an invalid template.

Their so called documentation is located here

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understand what you want, but there is no `${variable}` when using `#`.

If you want to execute some javascript, you would do something like this:

```
<p class="responsibilities">#= data.ResponsibilitiesHtml # </p>
```

Comment: I just want to render the HTML contained within the ResponsibilitiesHtml variable, using external templates as per demo here http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/index.html

Comment: Be advised: this is not how you are "supposed to do it". Your server should return a json object and ALL the html should be in your template where you fill in the names of the objects members via ${membername}.

Comment: Point taken - thanks, its server side generated HTML using a Markdown Parser, the Markdown is user generated, so i guess this is the only way to do it.

Comment: there are some javascript templating engines around which could possibly be of use to you. but in essence i agree. your framework should not limit, but make things easier for you . :)